# Dynamic linking boost libraries and the auto-link not working properly?

Tags: c++, boost, linker-errors, boost-thread, dynamic-linking

I used the following command to build `boost-1.53.0` on `Win7 Pro` with `VS 2013 Pro (VC12.0, 18.00.21005.1)`:

```
b2 stage toolset=msvc link=shared runtime-link=shared threading=multi --without-graph --without-graph_parallel --without-mpi --without-wave --without-python
```

And before that, I patched my source code as per this patch: [#8750 for_vs2013.patch](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/attachment/ticket/8750/for_vs2013.patch).

Finally I got the files under `$BOOST_ROOT/stage/lib` like these:

```
boost_atomic-vc120-mt-1_53.dll
boost_atomic-vc120-mt-1_53.lib
boost_atomic-vc120-mt-gd-1_53.dll
boost_atomic-vc120-mt-gd-1_53.lib
...
boost_thread-vc120-mt-1_53.dll
boost_thread-vc120-mt-1_53.lib
boost_thread-vc120-mt-gd-1_53.dll
boost_thread-vc120-mt-gd-1_53.lib
...
// only theses four files have "lib" prefix
libboost_exception-vc120-mt-1_53.lib
libboost_exception-vc120-mt-gd-1_53.lib
libboost_test_exec_monitor-vc120-mt-1_53.lib
libboost_test_exec_monitor-vc120-mt-gd-1_53.lib
```

I failed building `boost::signals` library. Since I don't know whether it's relative to this issue, I clarify it here.

I wrote a very simple demo to learn `boost::thread` according a tutorial just now. But the compiler gives me a link error: `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc120-mt-gd-1_53.lib'`. I searched around and I have a question. I'm sure I've set `Project Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation > Runtime Library` to `/MDd`. But why the compiler still tries to link the static library `libboost_thread-vc120-mt-gd-1_53.lib` when I rebuild the project? I also tried to use some relative solutions that I found, such as using `BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK` or `BOOST_DYN_LINK` precompile directive. But it's not working. I found such a snippet in `auto-link.hpp`:

```
//
// select linkage opt:
//
#if (defined(_DLL) || defined(_RTLDLL)) && defined(BOOST_DYN_LINK)
#  define BOOST_LIB_PREFIX
#elif defined(BOOST_DYN_LINK)
#  error "Mixing a dll boost library with a static runtime is a really bad idea..."
#else
#  define BOOST_LIB_PREFIX "lib"
#endif
```

It should work but I can't get the result I want :(

BTW, should I rebuild the boost libraries with `link=static` option?

### demo code

```
// c++ std libraries
#include <iostream>
// c++ boost libraries
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

// #define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK
// #define BOOST_DYN_LINK

void WorkerFunc()
{
    boost::posix_time::seconds worktime(3);
    std::cout << "Worker: running..." << std::endl;

    // Pretend to do sth. useful...
    boost::this_thread::sleep(worktime);

    std::cout << "Worker: finished." << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout << "main: startup." << std::endl;
    // Create a worker thread.
    boost::thread worker_thread(WorkerFunc);

    std::cout << "main: waiting for thread..." << std::endl;
    worker_thread.join();

    std::cout << "main: done." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After staring the demo code for a long time, finally I figured out. I should put `#define BOOST_DYN_LINK` before including the boost libraries' headers. I'm sorry for such a silly mistake. And it really took me a lot of time :(

Comment: I've come across the same problem. But why did you say "I have tried `BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK` or `BOOST_DYN_LINK` precompile directive but it's not working" in your question spec, while saying putting `#define BOOST_DYN_LINK` there should work in your comment? Aren't they of the same effect?

Comment: @zhangxaochen Plz have a look at my code, you'll find that the macros were put after including the headers. In my case, `Boost::thread` needs dynamical linkage. The macros should be put(defined) before including the headers. Only then can the headers know they are to link dynamically. eg. `#define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK` `#include <boost::thread.hpp>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From inside visual studio: go to your project and right click it to get the context menu. Go to properties. In the properties dialog go to:

Configuration Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor->Preprocessor Definitions

Try putting BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK (or BOOST_THREAD_USE_DLL) in the Preprocessor Definitions list.

Then rebuild your demo.